# resizing the last column of a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is used in two different views. In each case, I would like to have the last column resize it's width if the user resizes the host control/view.

How would you do that?

Cheers,
Berryl

...
    
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        >

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Number" Binding="{Binding BusinessId}" IsReadOnly="True" 
            CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="False"
            Width="75"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" 
            CanUserSort="True" SortDirection="Ascending" CanUserResize="True"
            MinWidth="260" Width="Auto"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

## UPDATE (Working Code)

I just named the column in the xaml and put the following code into the code-behind. If anyone has got a better idea or a way to optimize this, please let me know!

```
public partial class Listing : UserControl
{
    private double _currentColumnWidth;

    public Listing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentColumnWidth = colDescription.ActualWidth;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // split if control is not loaded yet
        if (_currentColumnWidth == 0) return;

        // only interested in width, not height
        var widthChanged = e.WidthChanged;
        if (!widthChanged) return;

        var delta = e.NewSize.Width - e.PreviousSize.Width;
        var newWidth = _currentColumnWidth + delta;
        if (newWidth <= colDescription.MinWidth || newWidth >= colDescription.MaxWidth) return;

        _currentColumnWidth = newWidth;
        colDescription.Width = new DataGridLength(_currentColumnWidth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just replace the width property in your XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" 
                IsReadOnly="True" 
                CanUserSort="True" SortDirection="Ascending" CanUserResize="True"
                MinWidth="260" Width="Auto"  />
```

to ...

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                CanUserSort="True" SortDirection="Ascending" CanUserResize="True"
                MinWidth="260" Width="*"  />
```

You do not require any code behind to do any handling of the width as WPF caters for this in XAML.

the "*" indicates an AutoSize value  :)

Comment: @Jason Ebersey. both * and Auto have autosizing ability, the difference being that Star "automatically sizes elements based on a weighted proportion of available space", while Auto "automatically sizes elements based on both the content of cells and the column headers". While I suspect your solution would work perfectly if the grid was just a control in a Window, it will not synchronize a column hosted inside a UserControl that is itself hosted in some other view container (try it that way and see!).

Comment: I probably didn't make it clear in my question that such was the situation I was looking to solve tho, so I'll mark this as the answer! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the code from my original posting 'update' and fixed a bug that was in it. Jason's suggestion to use "*" sizing is simpler and so should be used when a grid is not itself inside of a UserControl, but I am not aware of a better way to keep the column sized properly when it is inside a UserControl.

Cheers,
Berryl

The code below assumes there is a named DataGrid (ie, dgProject) and a named column (ie, colDescription) that needs to be resized when the control is resized.

```
public partial class Listing : UserControl
{

    public Listing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // split if control is not loaded yet
        if (!dgProject.IsLoaded) return;

        // only interested in width, not height
        if (!e.WidthChanged) return;

        var delta = e.NewSize.Width - e.PreviousSize.Width;
        var newWidth = colDescription.ActualWidth + delta;
        if (newWidth <= colDescription.MinWidth || newWidth >= colDescription.MaxWidth) return;

        colDescription.Width = new DataGridLength(newWidth);
    }
```